# Can't Connect to Cassandras default cluster (Test Cluster) Using Opscenter

Tags: cassandra, centos, cassandra-3.0, opscenter

My Error is as below
OpsCenter was not able to add the cluster: OpsCenter was unable to resolve the ip for Test_Cluster, please specify seed nodes using the rpc_address 
My OS is CentOS 7
I install DSE 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that datastax forbidden my ip